# How do I convert a date variable and time variable to one timestamp variable in php?

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I have a variable (startsAt) that is a date variable, and I have a variable (startsTime) that is a time variable.  I would like to combine those two variables into a timestamp and use that timestamp to update a database in SQL.  Can anybody help with this?

Comment: What do you mean by `Date` variable and `Time` variable? Are they `DateTime` objects?

Comment: You need examples of the variables and what's needed for the DB.

Comment: please add the code where your variables are defined/calculated

Comment: `strtotime( $startAt . ' '. $startTime )` http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php  assuming both are in valid formats. such as 'Y-m-d H:i:s', otherwise convert date to a timestamp and if time is in seconds ( or convert to seconds of the day) add it.

Answer (score 0):

HI  you can just concatenate the two and

```
   $timestamp = strtotime( $startAt . ' ' . $startTime );
```

assuming both are in valid date formats. such as 'Y-m-d H:i:s', for example you have a date Y-m-d and a time H:i:s, or in english  2016-06-15 and 17:25:00

php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php